# Validation for file type not working in File Upload in Magento 2 Store Configuration

Tags: magento2, configuration, file-upload, custom-validation

I am following below Article to upload file in store configuration:
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-file-upload-sytem-configuration-magento-2.html

I have defined custom backend model as mentioned in this artice to validate my file type:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Backend;

class CustomFileType extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File
{
    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions() {
        return ['csv'];
    }
}
?>
```

and in system.xml, it's like this:

```
<field id="import" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Import CSV</label>
                    <comment>Comment</comment>
                    <backend_model>Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Backend\CustomFileType</backend_model>
                    <upload_dir>upload</upload_dir>
</field>
```

but it's not working. I can upload image files too!!

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Code looks fine. Did you run di:compile and flushed the cache as well?

Comment: yes. I flushed the cache. do i need to run di:compile in developer mode too?

Comment: Yes run once because if not compiled then might be an issue.

Comment: Thank you @SukumarGorai. But i got the solution. See my answer.

Comment: Yes I have checked. Happy coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer by referring

> vendor\magento\module-config\Model\Config\Backend\File.php

Correct Function name is **_getAllowedExtensions** not **getAllowedExtensions**

So, correct method is:

```
public function _getAllowedExtensions() {
        return ['csv'];
    }
```

Comment: its not necessary

Comment: You can try this code!

Comment: i'm also try this

Answer (score 0):

**Replace backend_model with this :-**

```
<backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File</backend_model>
```

Comment: this is not working!

Comment: i think your controller is not called